# Getting run time error '1004' from copy and paste function

Tags: excel, runtime-error, with-statement, vba

am trying to write some code that will identify a value in a row, cut the entire row and then insert that row into row 2 (and shift the rows down) but I am getting a run time error 1004 saying something about the copy and paste areas must be the same size.  Can anyone help?  Code below:

```
With Sheets("xxx")
    For Lrow = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            With .Cells(Lrow, "J")
                If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                    If .Value = "Desk to adjust" Then
                        .EntireRow.Cut
                        Rows("2:2").Select
                        Selection.Insert shift:=xlDown
                        Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
                    End If
                End If
            End With
    Next Lrow
End With
```

The bug is in the line :

```
Selection.Insert shift:=xlDown
```

Thanks!!

Comment: This could be the issue? `.Rows(lrow).EntireRow.Cut`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ...

```
Dim wks           As Worksheet
Dim iRow          As Long

Set wks = Worksheets("xxx")

With wks
  For iRow = 3 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    If .Cells(iRow, "J").Value = "Desk to adjust" Then
      .Rows(iRow).Cut
      .Rows(2).Insert
      .Rows(2).NumberFormat = "0"
    End If
  Next iRow
End With
```

Note that the comparison is case-sensitive.

Comment: Also, you can't cut row 2 to row 2; you'll get the same error via the user interface.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the ranges where overlapping for row 2. You were trying to cut and paste to the same place which is not allowed

```
Sub test()
    With Sheets("xxx")
        For Lrow = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            With .Cells(Lrow, "J")
                If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                    If .Value = "Desk to adjust" Then
                        If Not Lrow = 2 Then
                            .EntireRow.Cut
                            Rows("2:2").Select
                            Selection.Insert shift:=xlDown
                            Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        Next Lrow
    End With
End Sub
```

Why don't you try a less loopy solution. It will save you a lot of time.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveToTop()

    Dim rData As Range
    Dim rToMove As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set rData = Sheets("xxx").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion

    ' Filter the data in Column J which is field 10
    rData.AutoFilter 10, "Desk to adjust"

    ' Turn off errors in case there is nothing filtered
    ' and cut and paste the data.
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rToMove = rData.Offset(1).Resize(rData.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    For i = 1 To rToMove.Areas.Count
        rToMove.Areas(i).EntireRow.Cut
        If Application.CutCopyMode = xlCut Then
            Sheets("xxx").Rows(2).Insert xlShiftDown
        End If
    Next i
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Remove the filter
    rData.AutoFilter

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub shiftRows()
    Dim lRow As Long
    With Sheets("xxx")
        For lRow = .UsedRange.Row To .UsedRange.Row + .UsedRange.Rows.Count
            With .Cells(lRow, .Columns("J").Column)
                If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                    If .Value = "Desk to adjust" And lRow > 2 Then
                        .EntireRow.Cut
                        .Rows(2).Insert shift:=xlDown
                        .Rows(2).NumberFormat = "0"
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        Next lRow
    End With
End Sub
```